# Trying to add an add-on with an license that covers it but am being forced to buy it

Tags: matlab

My university has a total headcount license that covers all major add-ons. I was able to install it, alongside the two add-ons I need (Image Processing Toolbox and Computer Vision System Toolbox) at home with the install wizard.

However, in the lab when I try to add these add-ons to my matlab environment (even when logging in) via the 'Get Add-Ons' option in the menu (Add-On Explorer), I am forced to 'Buy' each toolbox. i.e. I am not offered the option to download it, despite it being covered in my license. Any idea how to get this working/ alternative method?

I should also note, it's not possible to reinstall Matlab as I do not have the permissions required.

Comment: Are you logged in to Mathworks with the right user?

Comment: @EBH Yes, I'm absolutely sure. It's the same user I used to install Matlab at home (the only user I have access to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who arrives here after me, just use Matlab Online. Bit of an workaround but it's the only solution I found.

https://matlab.mathworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answer the question, but nowadays it is not essential to stick to Matlab. Python with OpenCV and Numpy, R are basically free options with no license hassle and lots of support. Plus, you will be able to use your code after graduation :o)